# I am writing some code for a login system in python and I can't seem to be able to have it read the email and password from a txt file

Tags: python, hashlib

```
import hashlib
def signup():
    email = input("Enter an email address: ")
    pwd = input("Enter a password: ")
    conf_pwd = input("Confirm your password: ")
    if conf_pwd == pwd:
        enc = conf_pwd.encode()
        hash1 = hashlib.sha256(enc).hexdigest()
        with open(r'D:\Python Programs\Login\database.txt', "a") as f:
             f.write(email + "\n")
             f.write(hash1 + "\n")
        f.close()
        print("You have registered successfully!")
    else:
        print("Password is not same as above! \nPlease try again")
        signup()
def login():
    email = input("Enter email: ")
    pwd = input("Enter password: ")
    auth = pwd.encode()
    auth_hash = hashlib.sha256(auth).hexdigest()
    with open(r'D:\Python Programs\Login\database.txt', "r") as f:
        stored_email, stored_pwd = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
    if email == stored_email and auth_hash == stored_pwd:
         print("Logged in Successfully!")
    else:
         print("Login failed! \nPlease try again")
         login()
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the [Insert Game Name Here]")
    HaveAccount = input("Have you made an account before? (Y/N): ")
    if HaveAccount == ("Y"):
        login()
    elif HaveAccount == ("N"):
        signup()
    else:
        print("Please enter either 'Y' or 'N'")
        welcome()


welcome()
```

It is specifically line 23 and it has a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) whenever I try and log in with an email and password. I need to add some extra text in because my post is mostly code and I don't know what else to say so here is some random typing to make more characters in my post. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: DO NOT use recursion like you do here.  Use a `while True` loop, and break when you are finished.

Comment: You should try using `f.readlines()`.  When you do split, you'll get 3 results: the email, the hash, and the null entry after the second newline.